# broken bone heal time

Tags: orthopedics, physiotherapy, broken-bones, weight-bearing-activity

I am lead to believe that a *minor break will take

6 months to become 99% strong.
12 months to become 100% strong.

A orthopaedic surgeon advised me of this.

With this in mind any activity that could damage the bone should be avoided for 6 months, such as mountain biking.

After talking to a physiotherapist I was advised that if physo goes well activities such as mountain biking could be done as early as 6 weeks as long as one does not fall.

So, 
6 weeks moderate exercises is fine, no risks to be taken. 
6 months not 100% healed but can resume more risky activities.

What would reasonable at 3,4 and 5 months.

I am thinking build it up to proper mountain biking from 3 to 6 and maybe a very minor fall at low speed would be ok at maybe 4 months.

Weight bearing exercises are also being done.

*minor break such as a humorous head break, no cracking of head clean break below the head.

-- Hypothetically, if someone was discharged from physio at 8 weeks due to doing so well and discharged from docs at about 10 weeks with the surgeon saying the patient is about 1 month ahead of where they need to be does this reduce the time? I would say not as bone still needs to bind although weight baring does help .

Any falling of is not planned, but as time moves by more technical trails would be ridden.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're asking for personal medical advice and we can't provide that. Most of us aren't doctors and those who are haven't examined you, know nothing of your history, haven't seen the x-rays, etc. I would run these questions past the physical therapist.

Comment: Yes, it is related to a personal experience but I am genuinely interested.. I might book an appointment with the GP.